# How to disable Jit dialog box on Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, jit

Me and my instructor did the same error on code but the way he is receiving "Exception Unhandled" message is different than the way i receive, he receive like a pop-up in code area like this;

[image]

But i receive in dialog box like this;

[image]

i made a research and found that i should disable JIT debugging, which i did by following these;

[disable JIT 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/just-in-time-jit-debugging-instead-of-this-dialog/bf40c177-14b5-464b-8f1a-7377265b9ba7)

[disable JIT 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

but no hope, i could not receive Errors like the instructor does, i want that kind of pop-up because it indicates the code which has error. Need your help.

Thank you.

Edit:

[madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection) asked detail about casting Error;

the TextBox in Casting is actually RichTextBox.

[image]

Comment: The Real Issue™ is that you're letting an exception go unhandled. You could wrap your whole `Main` in a `try`/`catch` block, but recovering from that is nigh on impossible. Don't do that. In your case, this comes down to a *developer exception*, something that you should never have to guard against if you do the correct cast in your code.

Comment: @madreflection but i always get this dialog box for every error and this does not light my path, i was using vs2017 community edition, i barely remember that i see that dialog box. thank you.

Comment: You need to fix the cast. Post the code as text. The cast that needs to be fixed isn't visible in the screenshot.

Comment: @madreflection , i did as you asked, the main idea is not receiving Errors in this dialog box. First Dialog Box is belong to this Error; " ((TextBox)F1GB1.Controls["txtuKategori"]).Text = (U1.urunKategori);" , it is not txtuKategori but txtKategori. for both errors and for all errors i receive in this Dialog Box.

Comment: You did *not* do as asked. The code is still in screenshot form. StackOverflow expects code to be posted as text. Post it as text. Anyway, cast it to `RichTextBox` instead. That's what the exception is telling you is incorrect.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you for your effort, but i am not asking to review and correct my code, i am asking to how to turn off this dialog box and use the pop-up like above.